# Google Pay Button in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-pay

I integrate Gpay in my flutter app and it's was working on the emulator but when I build it and run on my real Android device, the Gpay Button don't show, is it a country restriction or others issues.Thanks.

Comment: How are you integrating with Flutter? Are you using the following: https://github.com/google-pay/flutter-plugin? There are some country restrictions, which country are you integrating from?

Comment: I'm using pay from pub.dev, Country = Togo.

Comment: Hi! You can add a value to the [`onError` parameter in the button](https://github.com/google-pay/flutter-plugin/blob/main/pay/lib/src/widgets/pay_button.dart#L59) to learn more about the reason for the error. Take a look at the [conditions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/PaymentsClient#isReadyToPay(com.google.android.gms.wallet.IsReadyToPayRequest)) under which isReadyToPay returns `true` and `false`. See the [list of countries where Google Pay can be used online](https://support.google.com/pay/answer/9023773?hl=en#zippy=%2Cpay-online-or-in-apps).

Comment: @BitcoinTogoOfficiel were you able to implement the google pay with flutter

Answer (score 0):

Set google_pay.json in your assets directory and change your publish key, merchant id, and name in the json file.